# How to use HasAndBelongsToMany with a Dictionary in Castle.ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord

I'm trying to setup a set of data models like so:

```
[ActiveRecord, JoinedBase]
public class Locale : DataType
{
    private int m_id;
    private String m_DisplayName;
    private String m_Code;

    public Locale() 
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }

    [Property]
    public String DisplayName
    {
        get { return m_DisplayName; }
        set { m_DisplayName = value; }
    }

    [Property]
    public String Code
    {
        get { return m_Code; }
        set { m_Code = value; }
    }
}

[ActiveRecord, JoinedBase]
public class LocaleStringInstance : DataType
{
    private int m_id;
    private String m_text;

    public LocaleStringInstance() 
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }


    [Property]
    public String Text
    {
        get { return m_text; }
        set { m_text = value; }
    }
}

[ActiveRecord(Lazy=true), JoinedBase]
public class LocaleString : DataType
{
    private int m_id;
    private IDictionary<Locale, LocaleStringInstance> m_LocaleStrings;

    public LocaleString() 
    {
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return m_id; }
        set { m_id = value; }
    }

    [HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(LocaleStringInstance),
        RelationType.Map, ColumnRef="LS_Col_Ref", ColumnKey = "LocaleStringInstance_id", Table = "LocaleStringMapping", 
        RelationType = RelationType.Map, Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan,
        Lazy = true, Index = "Locale", IndexType= "Locale")]
    virtual public IDictionary<Locale, LocaleStringInstance> LocaleStrings 
    {
        get { return m_LocaleStrings; }
        set { m_LocaleStrings = value; }
    }
}
```

The main problem lies in trying to model the last property here, "LocaleStrings". 
The idea is that a particular LocaleString will have a string for each 'locale' that has been defined. The Dictionary is supposed to represent this.

Unfortunately when I try to register these types with ActiveRecord I get the following error:
ActiveRecordException: {"Could not determine type for: Locale, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Locale)"} System.Exception {NHibernate.MappingException}

This is because the "IndexType" is set to "Locale".. But what should it be set to? I've tried adding the full namespace to the beginning of Locale, which didn't work. I've also tried setting to string, and int, which naturally work during registration, but fail when I try to actually use the object because a Locale can't be converted to a string or integer.

Does anyone know how to use this RelationType.Map and IndexType properly? How can I acheive a model that does what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears that it is not possible to model the described relation using Castle.ActiveRecord at this time as it does not support the required parameters that NHibernate would need to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

try the assembly qualified name for Locale, ie: "NameSpace.For.Locale, LocaleAssembly"

Have you tried without specifying the Index Type? ActiveRecord should pick up the type from the generic arguments of the IDictionary<>

Comment: I've tried without indextype, but then it complains that an index type must be specified. I haven't tried a fully qualified name yet, I will try that. Though I don't understand why it doesn't work without an index type either

Comment: Does what I'm trying to achieve sound reasonable? Have you tried something like this before? Modelling a dictionary with a complex type as the key?

Comment: It is reasonable, but you need to implement GetHashCode and Equals properly on Locale especially

Comment: Hmm, it still gave me this: Could not determine type for: LocaleLibrary.Locale, LocaleLibrary, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Locale)

Comment: I have also tried the full assembly qualified name now too, but it gives the same problem:

{"Could not determine type for: LocaleLibrary.Locale, LocaleLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Locale)"}

Thanks anyway...
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I've looked at the source code for ActiveRecord and it seems like it doesn't support the NHibernate mapping for <index-many-to-many> that's needed to use an entity class as a key in a dictionary mapping, sorry about that. Your best bet would be to just use a string identifier for the Locale if you can as the key

Comment: Thats unfortunate... 
Is there any way to model this domain with the tools that are available? I imagine a string ID for the locale could leave me open to potential inconsistencies in the DB (i.e. nothing but the UI stopping invalid keys being used in the maps), or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: You can add a unique key on your Locale table to code, and then a foreign key on LocaleStringMapping pointing to Locale.code.  Alternatively you can access the NHibernate configuration via                 var config = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().GetConfiguration(typeof (ActiveRecordBase)) and then modify that configuration to add the mapping you want

Comment: Am I able to setup a FK inside LocaleStringMapping using ActiveRecord? It sounds like what I'm already trying to do...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11644/discussion-between-joshg-and-martin-ernst)